# jQuery datatables grouped row with biggest number in another column to appear first

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Assuming that I have a row grouping table which groups by browser and i want the browser that has the latest engine version to be displayed first. Is there any way to do it? I've tried a few variations and "cheats" by putting engine version before browser but it ends up being separated....

E.g. In the scenario from [Datatables row grouping example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html), instead of KHTML being on top, I would like for Trident to be on top since Trident has the biggest engine version (Internet Explorer 7) and Internet Explorer 7 will be at the top of Trident's group. Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: Do you need to sort according other columns largest value, or is it possible for you to insert another hidden column with largest group value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. To achieve this you need to add another column which will contain all your ordering value. Let me explain: Your Modified Table structure would be like :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Rendering engine Max V</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the second column will contain the maximum version number of Rendering engine group

And your JavaScript code should be like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
        "fnDrawCallback": function ( oSettings ) {
            if ( oSettings.aiDisplay.length == 0 )
            {
                return;
            }

            var nTrs = $('tbody tr', oSettings.nTable);
            var iColspan = nTrs[0].getElementsByTagName('td').length;
            var sLastGroup = "";
            for ( var i=0 ; i<nTrs.length ; i++ )
            {
                var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
                var sGroup = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex] ]._aData[0];
                if ( sGroup != sLastGroup )
                {
                    var nGroup = document.createElement( 'tr' );
                    var nCell = document.createElement( 'td' );
                    nCell.colSpan = iColspan;
                    nCell.className = "group";
                    nCell.innerHTML = sGroup;
                    nGroup.appendChild( nCell );
                    nTrs[i].parentNode.insertBefore( nGroup, nTrs[i] );
                    sLastGroup = sGroup;
                }
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] },
            { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [ 1 ] }
        ],
        "aaSortingFixed": [[ 1, 'desc' ], [ 0, 'asc' ]],
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        "sDom": 'lfr<"giveHeight"t>ip'
    });
} );
```

That's it! You can find [Script Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/PJk44/)

Enjoy!